# upgrading apk file in android market

Tags: android

i sell the application into android market with the version 1. i upgrade the application with version 2.in that version 2 i found one bug after upgrading.now i resolved that bug

is it possible to upgrade application ith version2

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put up a version 3 with that bug resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you mean that:

1. You published an app to the Market, at version 1
2. You upgraded the app, in the market, to version 2
3. You discovered that that upgrade had a bug in it and you now want to publish a new upgrade

If that's the case then you have to post a new version as version 3. However, remember that there are two things you control when posting new versions. There's the versionName which can be anything you want and then the versionCode which must be a number and each release must have a higher number than the previous one. The versionCode is how the Android Market knows if the version in the Market is more up to date than the version on someone's phone. The version name is just the name people see when looking at the app in the market. So in your case you must change the versionCode to 3, but you could keep the version name as "version 2".

Answer (score 1):

It's friendlier to increase both your versionCode & your versionName. In most of the development shops I've worked at, we used a minimum of 2 digits to signify a release.  The first is the major release number 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc.  The second or minor release (small features added or fixed). A third can be for very small bug fixes or emergency point releases.  So in this case you could have a 2.1 release or 2.0.1 since it was a minor bug fix to existing functionality.